# Select MAX row (latest event) for each user (two table join with conditions)

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, select, greatest-n-per-group

I'm new to Postgres and having an issue with what seems like a simple task.. I've read through many examples and a lot of them occur with just a single table so I'm here for help!

I have a users table and an events table.

Users consists of user_id, name, user_type

Events consists of event_id, user_id, event_name, event_type, event_date

I want to get the latest events for each user where user_type = full and event_type = paid

I've tried the following but Postgres tells me "ERROR: Column "e.event_name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"

```
select 
  u.user_id, 
  u.user_type, 
  max(e.event_id), 
  e.event_name 
from 
  users u 
  join events e on u.user_id = e.user_id 
where 
  u.user_type = 'full' 
  and e.event_type = 'paid' 
group by 
  u.user_id
```

Note: Some solutions mentioned DISTINCT ON but system I'm using doesn't think that's valid SQL.

Comment: If the system you are using does not support `distinct on` then you are not using Postgres

Comment: Thanks it's an analytics system with it's own error checking, they're definitely on postgres but it's throwing an error :-|

Comment: This is a faq & a tag: "greatest n per group". Why are you trying to do this, it doesn't make sense. Group by partitions the table's rows into a group of rows per subtuple value then you can select group by columns and/or new values that are a function of the group. What do you think selecting a non-aggregated non-grouping column means? It has a possibly different value for every row in a partition.

Comment: This is a faq. Please always google error messages & many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've seen, you can't mix row and aggerate functions like that.
One common approach is to use the `row_number` window function to sort events by their date (per user), and then just take the first ones:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT *,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY u.user_id ORDER BY event_date DESC) AS rn
        FROM   users u
        JOIN   events e ON u.user_id = e.user_id
        WHERE  user_type = 'full' AND
               event_type = 'paid') t
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient method in Postgres is often to use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (u.user_id) u.user_id, u.user_type, 
       e.event_id, e.event_name 
from users u join
     events e
     on u.user_id = e.user_id 
where u.user_type = 'full' and
      e.event_type = 'paid' 
order by u.user_id, e.event_date desc;
```